# Filtrar valor de coluna e extrair destas linhas de outra coluna o valor e escrever numa nova coluna

Tags: python, pandas

Preciso de um help, to apanhando pacas. Tenho o titulo como mostra a tabela da esquerda e preciso transformar com o Pandas no formato da tabela em amarelo, será que o Pandas da conta?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Estou com 3 colunas e mais de 1000 linhas. Existem aleatoriamente linhas que possuem informação diferente de todas as demais. Nessas em questão, tem na primeira coluna todas o mesmo valor, vide abaixo essa linha inteira:

```
col1      col2      col3
-------------------------------------------------
FIG.      Item      Nomes diferentes nesta coluna
```

Em todas essas linhas que tem a coluna com o valor *"FIG."*; isto é, o que diferencia essas linhas das outras.

Preciso filtrar essas linhas (com o "FIG.") e pegar o valor desta linha que é um texto que esta na terceira coluna e criar uma quarta coluna com esse valor. Podem me ajudar com isso? Ficaria algo assim:

```
col1      col2      col3                               col4
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
FIG.      Item      Nomes diferentes nesta coluna      Nomes diferentes nesta coluna
```

Após isso quero voltar ao `DataFrame` que contém todas as linhas antes de filtrar porém que fique com essa quarta coluna.

Fiz isso e o filtro funcionou:

```
df_mask = df['FIG.'] =='FIG.' filtered_df = df[df_mask] lista = filtered_df
```

E isso também funcionou:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(lista,columns=['FIG.','Item','Nomes diferentes nesta coluna'])
```

Mas não estou conseguindo criar uma nova coluna com os valores *"Nomes diferentes nesta coluna"*.

Comment: Luiz, a descrição está um pouco confusa para entender. Você poderia atualizar seu post, colocando 3 linhas do seu dataframe original e a saída que você espera?

Comment: Luiz Notari, não rasure as perguntas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A grande dificuldade de usar o Pandas é pensar que se consegue fazer tudo em uma linha. Talvez seja possível, mas não é legível e é de difícil manutenção.

Sendo assim, vamos por partes

### Criando base de teste

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({"FigField": ["FIG", "",  "",  "", "FIG",  "",  "",  "", "FIG",  "",  ""], "CatFilme": ["Categoria 1", "filme a",  "filme b",  "filme c", "Categoria 2",  "filme x",  "filme y",  "filme z", "Categoria 3",  "filme h",  "filme k"]})
```

Temos:

```
   FigField     CatFilme
0       FIG  Categoria 1
1                filme a
2                filme b
3                filme c
4       FIG  Categoria 2
5                filme x
6                filme y
7                filme z
8       FIG  Categoria 3
9                filme h
10               filme k
```

### Criando coluna auxiliar "zerada"

```
df["ColAux"] = np.nan
```

Temos

```
   FigField     CatFilme  ColAux
0       FIG  Categoria 1     NaN
1                filme a     NaN
2                filme b     NaN
3                filme c     NaN
4       FIG  Categoria 2     NaN
5                filme x     NaN
6                filme y     NaN
7                filme z     NaN
8       FIG  Categoria 3     NaN
9                filme h     NaN
10               filme k     NaN
```

### Copiando a categoria para a coluna auxiliar somente onde existe FIG

```
df["ColAux"] = df.apply(lambda row: row["CatFilme"] if row["FigField"] == "FIG" else np.nan, axis=1)
```

Temos

```
   FigField     CatFilme       ColAux
0       FIG  Categoria 1  Categoria 1
1                filme a          NaN
2                filme b          NaN
3                filme c          NaN
4       FIG  Categoria 2  Categoria 2
5                filme x          NaN
6                filme y          NaN
7                filme z          NaN
8       FIG  Categoria 3  Categoria 3
9                filme h          NaN
10               filme k          NaN
```

### Preenchendo os NaN da coluna auxiliar com a categoria

```
df["ColAux"].fillna(method="ffill", inplace=True)
```

Temos

```
   FigField     CatFilme       ColAux
0       FIG  Categoria 1  Categoria 1
1                filme a  Categoria 1
2                filme b  Categoria 1
3                filme c  Categoria 1
4       FIG  Categoria 2  Categoria 2
5                filme x  Categoria 2
6                filme y  Categoria 2
7                filme z  Categoria 2
8       FIG  Categoria 3  Categoria 3
9                filme h  Categoria 3
10               filme k  Categoria 3
```

### Apagando linhas que contenham FIG

```
df = df[df["FigField"] != "FIG"]
```

Temos

```
   FigField CatFilme       ColAux
1            filme a  Categoria 1
2            filme b  Categoria 1
3            filme c  Categoria 1
5            filme x  Categoria 2
6            filme y  Categoria 2
7            filme z  Categoria 2
9            filme h  Categoria 3
10           filme k  Categoria 3
```

Ainda pode ser feito o `reset_index()` caso ache interessante.

Comment: @LuizNotari, que bom que funcionou. Sendo assim, marque a resposta como aceita.

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que você esteja procurando `stack()` ou `unstack()`

Para lembrar o que cada um faz, o `stack` deixará seu data frame mais longo, e o `unstack` mais largo.

Uma vez que não tenho acesso aos dados, segue um exemplo.

```
>>> import pandas as pd

>>> frutas = ['banana', 'abacaxi', 'ameixa', 'banana', 'abacaxi']
>>> valores = [1.0, 1.0, 2.0, 5.0, 3.5]

>>> df = pd.DataFrame({"fruta": frutas, "valor": valores})

>>> df
     fruta  valor
0   banana    1.0
1  abacaxi    1.0
2   ameixa    2.0
3   banana    5.0
4  abacaxi    3.5
```

### Criando o grupo

```
>>> df.groupby("fruta").agg('sum')
         valor
fruta
abacaxi    4.5
ameixa     2.0
banana     6.0
```

### Stacking

```
>>> df.groupby("fruta").agg('sum').stack()
fruta
abacaxi  valor    4.5
ameixa   valor    2.0
banana   valor    6.0
dtype: float64
```

### Unstacking

```
>>> df.groupby("fruta").agg('sum').unstack()
       fruta
valor  abacaxi    4.5
       ameixa     2.0
       banana     6.0
dtype: float64
>>>
```

### Criando grupo pelas duas colunas

```
>>> df.groupby(["fruta", "valor"]).agg({'valor': 'sum'})
               valor
fruta   valor
abacaxi 1.0      1.0
        3.5      3.5
ameixa  2.0      2.0
banana  1.0      1.0
        5.0      5.0
```

### Escolhendo a coluna para unstack

```
>>> df.groupby(["fruta", "valor"]).agg({'valor': 'sum'}).unstack()
        valor
valor     1.0  2.0  3.5  5.0
fruta
abacaxi   1.0  NaN  3.5  NaN
ameixa    NaN  2.0  NaN  NaN
banana    1.0  NaN  NaN  5.0
```

### Preenchendo NaN com zero

```
>>> df.groupby(["fruta", "valor"]).agg({'valor': 'sum'}).unstack(fill_value=0)
        valor
valor     1.0  2.0  3.5  5.0
fruta
abacaxi   1.0  0.0  3.5  0.0
ameixa    0.0  2.0  0.0  0.0
banana    1.0  0.0  0.0  5.0
```

Veja a documentação dos dois: [stack](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) e [unstack](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html)

**Em tempo**: este é apenas um exemplo sem nenhuma aplicação específica e serviu apenas para explorar os métodos `stack()` e `unstack()` que te ajudarão com seu caso.

Comment: Criei uma nova resposta para sua pergunta, mas resolvi manter esta pois pode ser útil para os demais